# How to loop through all dynamically created linkbuttons on preinit event of page in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created linkbuttons on preinit event of page now I want to loop through all the linkbuttons on preinit event of page. My page has a masterpage and my linkbuttons are placed in the panel and that panel is also created dynamically.

```
DataView ReportDataView = new DataView(FullReportData, "ReportSection = '" + ReportSection + "' and IsAdminAccess = 'Y' ", "SerialNumber", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);//Filter data on basis of different sections available and visibility flag in tbl_Reports

DataTable DataTableToMakePanelAndButtons = ReportDataView.ToTable();//Convert dataview to datatable

foreach(Control control in Page.Controls)
{
 if (control is LinkButton)
 {
   foreach(DataRow row in DataTableToMakePanelAndButtons.Rows)
   {
    if (Convert.ToString(row[0]) == control.ID)
     {
       row.Delete();
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more info on what you are trying to achieve and what problem you have encountered is?

Comment: Yeah - you have more than one issue going on with that code, and we need to know what you're trying to accomplish...